# Get PHP value using JS in Android Webview

Tags: java, php, android, webview, android-volley

I researched a lot on this before asking this question. Even tried ChatGPT.

I am using Volley to send HTTP request from android webview to my PHP app that runs in the webview to a specific page for inserting the FCM token that is being generated. This works well but it works on every page load as the volley code is written within `onPgeFinished()` method in `MainFragment.java` file. Therefore, once the token is successfully inserted, I want to check first if the generated token in the webview is different than the token inserted into the database before making the Volley request as it is making the page load slow and unnecessarily creates an HTTP request every time a the page is freshly loaded / refreshed. For this I need to get the user specific token value from the database and send it to the webview's `MainFragment.java` file. Upon a lot of research and chatGPT usage I tried the following:

JS in my website:

```
<script>
  MyApp.userToken("<?php echo $token; ?>");
</script>
```

Then in the webview:

JavaScriptAPI.java

```
public class JavaScriptAPI {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private volatile String activeToken;

    public JavaScriptAPI(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }
    
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void userToken(String token){
        activeToken = token; // RECEIVES TOKEN SUCCESSFULLY AND OUTPUTS IN THE LOG BELOW
        Logcat.d("Received Token: " + activeToken);
    }

    public String getActiveToken() {
        return activeToken; // DOESN'T SET THE TOKEN RECEIVED IN THE ABOVE METHOD AND ALWAYS RETURNS NULL ( WHY ? )
    }
}
```

Then in MainFragment.java I try to call `getActiveToken()` to get the value so that I can use it.

MainFragment.java

```
JavaScriptAPI javaScriptAPI = new JavaScriptAPI(getActivity());
String phpVariableValue = javaScriptAPI.getActiveToken();
Logcat.d("PHP token value: " + phpVariableValue); // ALWAYS RETURNS NULL
```

I need to get the token value in `phpVariableValue` so that I can use it in a `if` statement and match it with the webview generated token value before creating volley request. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I got an alternate solution that works. I don't know why it always happens that when I am struggling for days searching for a solution, I never get it. But as soon as I post a question on stackoverflow, I find the solution myself .

Anyways, the workaround is, I get the token value in a text field (you can use div or span or anything with data attribute if you want. Have it your way!).

In website:

```
<input type="text" id="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
```

In Webview:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  private String kvToken;

  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url) {
   
    // GET TOKEN VALUE FROM WEBSITE
    mWebView.evaluateJavascript(
    "(function() { return document.getElementById('kvToken').value; })();",
    new ValueCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        kvToken = value.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
      }
    });

    Logcat.d("KV: " + kvToken);

    // USE kvToken HERE AS YOU WANT
  }
}
```

That's it. I struggled for a whole week just for such a solution. Good luck.

Oh and yes, thank you ChatGPT .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Of course you can do like that. But for me, i never use javascript interface to get value. Its better get value from java async task. And then using javascript interface to put value from android to php.